# How do I update an existing entity with data via Linq-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq-to-Xml to read XML and update an existing data structure.  Right now I have the following code to do this:

```
        // Load all the test plan details
        var details = doc.Descendants()
                         .Select(x => new
                         {
                             Name = x.Attribute("name").ToStringValue(),
                             DbName = x.Attribute(DATABASE_ATTR).ToStringValue(),
                             Login = x.Attribute(USERNAME_ATTR).ToStringValue(),
                             Password = x.Attribute(PASSWORD_ATTR).ToStringValue(),
                             AppSource = x.Attribute(APPSOURCE_ATTR).ToStringValue()
                         })
                         .First();


        testPlan.Name = details.Name;
        testPlan.DatabaseName = details.DbName;
        testPlan.LoginUsername = details.Login;
        testPlan.LoginPassword = details.Password;
        testPlan.ApplicationSource = details.AppSource;
    }
```

This is kind of annoying to me because I have to create a temp variable and perform the data transfer.  Is there any way for me to update the `testPlan` variable straight from within the Linq statement, which would cut down one step?  I could not get it to work by adding the update code into the `.Select()` statement.

Comment: LINQ is Language INtegrated *Query*; it is intentionally difficult (or impossible in some cases) to update objects when using it. Given that you're creating a new object in the `Select`, though, why not just use that one? Or, instead, `new` up an instance of whatever type `testPlan` is, so you don't have to do any assignments.

Comment: because the existing test plan structure has data that I am not wanting to change or null out.  I am merely trying to update it with some data queried from xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
doc.Descendants().First()
   .Select(x => 
           {
               testPlan.Name= x.Attribute("name").ToStringValue();
               testPlan.DatabaseName = x.Attribute(DATABASE_ATTR)
                                        .ToStringValue();
               testPlan.LoginUsername = x.Attribute(USERNAME_ATTR)
                                         .ToStringValue();
               testPlan.LoginPassword = x.Attribute(PASSWORD_ATTR)
                                         .ToStringValue();
               testPlan.ApplicationSource = x.Attribute(APPSOURCE_ATTR)
                                             .ToStringValue();
               return testPlan;
           })
    .ToList();
```

The call to `First` in the middle is to ensure, that only the attributes of the first descendant will be assigned to the properties of `testPlan`. The `ToList` at the end is used to really execute the code inside `Select`.

Although this works, I don't recommend using it, because it uses LINQ in a way it wasn't created for. Furthermore, it's easy to create it wrong:

- If you forget the `First`, testPlan will contain the attribute values of the **last** element in your XML, because the select code is executed for each element and overwrites the properties.
- If you forget the call to `ToList` or a similar method that forces the execution, the code inside `Select` will never be executed.

So, basically, the problem is, that you create a lot of possibilities to introduce a bug.

I would implement something like this in the following way:

```
var x = doc.Descendants.First();
testPlan.Name= x.Attribute("name").ToStringValue();
testPlan.DatabaseName = x.Attribute(DATABASE_ATTR).ToStringValue();
testPlan.LoginUsername = x.Attribute(USERNAME_ATTR).ToStringValue();
testPlan.LoginPassword = x.Attribute(PASSWORD_ATTR).ToStringValue();
testPlan.ApplicationSource = x.Attribute(APPSOURCE_ATTR).ToStringValue();
```

This is shorter, easier to read and doesn't violate LINQ to do something it wasn't created for.

Comment: ahh I didn't have the { } in my attempt at this, and that's why I couldn't get this to work.  Out of curiosity why don't you recommend using this?

Comment: @KallDrexx: See updated answer. It shows how I would do it. Also see the first sentence of dlev's comment to your question.

Comment: Oh, I guess that does make more sense.

Comment: @KallDrexx: Please check answer again. I updated it again, explaining the problems with the LINQ approach.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a constructor in the TestPlan class that takes a argument of type details?

Then just call testPlan = new TestPlan(details);

Comment: I don't want to instantiate a new `TestPlan`, I just want to update specific details based on the XML